# factorial in javascript without looping

Tags: javascript, function, recursion, factorial

How this factorial works without while or for loop i cant understand someone please explain

```js
function factorial(x) {

  if (x === 0) {
    return 1;
  }
  return x * factorial(x - 1);

}
console.log(factorial(5));
```

Comment: google recursion

Comment: Try stepping through it with the debugger.

Comment: You can watch videos related recursion in youtube. Videos will clarify better.

Answer (score 0):

It uses a recursive function. So `factorial` calls itself as many times, as long as x is not 0.